# Python ImportError - correctly importing file but error on importing contained function

Tags: python, python-import

I am getting an `ImportError` as `ImportError: cannot import name filter_name`
on executing `FilterTest.py` with only this line `from Filter2D import filter_name`
I can easily import functions from other `.py` files, but going the same route with `filter_name` function from `FilterTest.py`, I get this error. I could only find ImportErrors problems related to cyclic imports, and I can't reduce this to it. What am I doing wrong?

```
try2/
        - asian.py
            - toAsian()

        - europe.py
            - man2euro()
            - euro2asian()

        - Filter2D.py
            -- from FilterMain import filter
            - filter_name() -> filter()

        - FilterMain.py
            -- from asian import toAsian
            -- from europe import euro2asian
            - filter() -> toAsian(), euro2asian()

        - FilterTest.py
            #-- from asian import toAsian       # works well
            #-- from europe import euro2asian   # works well
            #-- import Filter2D                 # works well
            -- from Filter2D import filter_name # ImportError: cannot import name filter_name
```

Comment: Can you update how your Filter2D.py looks like?

Comment: Is `try2` supposed to be a package?

Comment: Thanks. I have already added the functions contained within a file with "-", whom they call with "->" and import statements with "--". What more info should I be adding?

Comment: Yeah, all the files are within the same folder in Windows, namely try2.

Comment: Please create a [stand-alone, working](http://sscce.org/) example. Your question now is too generic, and leaves people having to guess too much.

Comment: Being in the same folder doesn't imply it's a package: is there a `__init__.py` file in that folder?

Comment: Oh, I will add the same in the most concise form as soon as possible, thank you.

Comment: It's in particular this part that you may have gotten incorrect: `- filter_name() -> filter()`.